# Duplicate bits in a big numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, bit-manipulation

I have a big numpy array (i.e. approx. 2 ** 32 positions) of 64-bit unsigned integers and I want to duplicate a single bit (can vary from 0 to 63) in every integer inside this array.

---

Example:

- Input array: `array([ 0,  5,  2,  7 ])`
- Position (right to left) to duplicate: `0`

The input, in binary, is

```
000  101  010  111
```

After the operation, I want the bits as

```
0000 1011 0100 1111
```

- Result: `array([ 0,  11,  4,  15 ])`

---

As stated, my arrays are huge, so I'd prefer to use the lowest number of temporary / auxiliar arrays.

I tried to find something close to it in Google or even [Bit Twiddling Hacks](https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html) with no luck.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is far too straightforward to end up in the bit twiddling hacks list: `(x << 1) | (x & 1)`.

Comment: @user2357112 this only works when position = 0. Any bit can be duplicated.

Comment: Do you want to duplicate the same bit position in every integer? Or will the bit you want to duplicate vary?

Comment: @sgrg It's the same position in every integer

Comment: Still too straightforward: `part1 = x & -(1 << pos); part2 = x & ((1 << (pos+1))-1); return (part1 << 1) | part2;`. Select two pieces of the integer overlapping at the duplicated bit, and paste those pieces together without overlapping.

Comment: For reducing temporaries, you'd use the usual combination of common subexpression elimination, in-place operators, and ufuncs with `out` parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Implementation

The naive way already seems pretty efficient to me:

```
mask = -1 << (pos + 1)
(x << 1) & mask | x & ~mask
```

#### Benchmark

I ran the code as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import time

array = np.arange(2 ** 27, dtype=np.uint64)
pos = 5

t = time.process_time()
mask = np.uint64(-1 << (pos + 1))
array = (array << 1) & mask | array & ~mask
print(time.process_time() - t)
```

The bit duplication took 0.95 seconds (average of several runs).
Due to memory issues, I used only 2<sup>27</sup> entries. But we can expect the time for 2<sup>32</sup> entries to be 2<sup>32-27</sup> × 0.95 *s* = 2<sup>5</sup> × 0.95 *s* = 32 × 0.96 *s* = 30.4 *s*.